# How can I stop inline C# from adding a space to a element on a View in MVC ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a code chunck below that is being output with a space in the element when it's formated as shown and the condition is false. If I put it on one line it generates the required output. What I'm after is a more elegant solution. Any ideas?

Code Formated:

```
        <ul class="drop-menu-top dropdown-menu">
        <% if (propertyClass == PropertyClass.Overseas) { %>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Menus/OverseasPrimaryNav"); %>
        <% } %>
        </ul>
```

Output:

```
        <ul class="drop-menu-top dropdown-menu"> </ul>
```

Required Output:

```
        <ul class="drop-menu-top dropdown-menu" />
```

or

```
        <ul class="drop-menu-top dropdown-menu"></ul>
```

Thanks,

Denis

Comment: This sounds more like the request of a perfectionist/OCD sufferer than an actual problem. :) Is this strictly needed?!

Comment: i would have to admit to being a perfectionist/OCD sufferer at times. But it was needed till I decided to use jquery to check that the length of the returned string was greater than 1.

Comment: I am trying to fix the same issue here. There should be a more elegant way rather than the @eglasius answer. Because i always use the CTRL + K,D keyboard shortcut to format the document.

Comment: Might look at the Razor viewengine. Not sure if it would change the output but it definitely will change the look of the C#, so you never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<ul class="drop-menu-top dropdown-menu"><% 
   if (propertyClass == PropertyClass.Overseas) { %>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Menus/OverseasPrimaryNav"); %>
<% } %></ul>
```

Comment: Is there any elegant solution rather than this ?